# Counting/Enumerating Minimal Edge Covers

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, graph-theory, graph-algorithms, counting-complexity

A Minimal Edge Cover is an Edge Cover such that no other Edge Cover is a proper subset of it.

> **Questions**
>
> 1. Which is the complexity of counting Minimal Edge Covers? Do we know any non-trivial upper bound on their number? Is there any clever algorithm in literature to enumerate them?
> 2. Empirically, I'm observing that the number of Minimal Edge Covers seems to be always odd: so far in my experiments I've never met a graph having an even number of them. Is this a theoretically proven fact? If not, has their parity been investigated in literature?

Comment: Doesn't $C_4$, the cycle graph on 4 vertices, have two minimal edge covers?

Answer (score 3):

- Counting edge covers is #P-complete. You can find a proof here [Graph Orientations with No Sink and an Approximation for a Hard Case of #SAT](https://dblp.org/rec/conf/soda/BubleyD97). See also the [stack-exchange discussion](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/21279/complexity-of-counting-the-number-of-edge-covers-of-a-graph). One can probably modify the proof to show #P-completeness for minimal edge covers.
- enumerating (minimal) edge covers can be done with polynomial delay as the hypergraph has bounded degree (see [New Results on Monotone Dualization and Generating Hypergraph Transversals](https://epubs.siam.org/doi/10.1137/S009753970240639X))
- the following [Low-Exponential Algorithm for Counting the Number of Edge Covers on Simple Graphs](http://dx.doi.org/10.13053/cys-21-3-2244) claims an $O(1.465575^{(m−n)} × (m + n))$ time algorithm. I am wondering whether one cannot do better.